Why is Windows Store is damaged after last Windows 11 update and how can I repair it?
After the latest Windows 11 update a few days ago, several apps did not run anymore.

The log-in PIN does not work anymore and cannot be reestablished

Any app that is available on the Windows Store, like Notepad, Calculator, Messenger, and the Store itself, causes an error message (my OS is in Spanish):

"Pedir permiso
Deberás solicitar permiso a un adulto de la familia para poder usar: Microsoft Store."
Button: "Request it via email"
(Meaning "Ask an adult in your family to use Microsoft Store")



The button does nothing.
Originally, I was registered as an admin in MS Family Safety with my correct birthdate (never as a "child"), and my wife was the only family member. After this error occurred, I tried the following, but nothing helped:

I eliminated the family group and left it myself.
I uninstalled the related Windows app
After a long chat with MS, I deleted the related folders, which were empty anyway after the uninstall.
when this did not help either, I edited the Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Parental Controls\, setting Parental control to disabled and eliminating the registered identities.'

Even this did not change anything, probably because the app had been uninstalled before. (I have a backup copy of the key). I hoped that Store referred to these keys and would stop giving errors if the Parental Control was off.
So, in my understanding, notwithstanding the misleading error message, this is not caused by parental control but by some settings in the Windows Store. However, I have not yet found the registry keys for the Store.
While the system works for almost everything else, not being able to use frequently needed apps like Notepad, Calculator, and Messenger among others, is annoying. Before I make a clean install, which would take many days to reinstall all apps, some of which are not available anymore, I would like to resolve the problem at its root without affecting anything else.
Does anybody know where the Store reg key is and which settings need to be corrected? I understand that Store uses an API, I have seen as much in the registry. but I would not want to intervene there without knowing what I am doing. The Parental control was not very risky as I had eliminated it anyway.

Update: As requested, here are some other things I tried:

I undid the update, which was version 24H2, but it did not resolve the problem.
I applied DISM, no errors.
SFC did not run because there was an "update waiting", probably because I had undone it. So I updated again and then ran SFC. No errors. Unfortunately, there was no restore point.
It was suggested I try Reset-AppxPackage. I am missing information about this method. I tried elevated Powershell with Get-AppxPackage "Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe" | Reset-AppxPackage.
But nothing visible happened and the problem remains.

I also unregistered Windows Store with
Remove-AppxPackage -Package "Microsoft.WindowsStore_22410.1401.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
It disappeared from "Start", Then I added it again:
Get-AppXPackage WindowsStore -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
It reappeared but the problem remained.
Last update (15 Nov 2024:
After having tried all proposed solutions without success and not being able to roll back the update (Option "Go Back"), I have decided to abandon these attempts and reinstall the system from an older  backup. I also have problems with this, but I will start another question about this. Thanks to everybody who contributed with ideas and guidance.

The registry is increasingly vestigial, especially for fully "modern" apps. Keys may exist, but they may be used more to enable other older management tools like GPO to integrate with these modern systems and do not actually control the application's behavior. Have you performed the normal Windows repair functions, the DISM commands, SFC, etc? These should all be step one for the broad problems you're experiencing. Also, doing a system restore to a point prior to the update should be considered.

Thank you. The first thing I did was undo the update.
After leaving Parental Control, I applied DISM. SFC did not run because there was an "update waiting", probably because I had undone it. So I updated again and then ran SFC. No errors.   Unfortunately, there was no restore point. All valid points, but they did not help. I did not mention everything I did. I ran also CCleaner on the registry, without change. Then I went personally into the registry and changed the Parental Control keys. But as you say, they had probably no function anyway. I still hope that Store uses the registry.

Have you tried Reset-AppxPackage? You deleted what folders? I hope you didn't delete folders within WindowApps if you did then you have made it impossible for me to diagnose the issue. There likely isn't a registry key. This sounds like you should uninstall the update that was installed.  Which makes me wonder, what update, did you install exactly? Any additional information or error messages must be in English otherwise I cannot help.

@Ramhound, thanks for commenting. Regarding "what update", it's the Windows 11 24H2 update. When I wanted to suspend the PC, there was the "Update and restart" option in the menu and I did just this. The folder that I eliminated under the remote guidance of an MS employee was the folder related to Parental control. The folder was empty, probably as a result of uninstalling the Parental Control App in an attempt to eliminate the error pop-up whenever I try to access the Windows Store or any of the related app. I translated the error message to English. Any help is appreciated.

You only answer a fraction of the questions I asked. You also didn’t edit your question to include the information I asked for.

@Ramhound, I have not tried Reset-AppxPackage. I don't know what it is and where to find it. But here is another info. I found this page https://www.makeuseof.com/unblock-microsoft-store-app-windows-11 and looked for registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Microsoft > WindowsStore. It is missing, but is missing also in another PC that works well.

@Ramhound, I think I answered all your questions. The comment has a limited length. Please ask again if I did not answer all questions. I am not aware that I did not.

The reason I mentioned editing your question is due to the restrictions of a comment

When comments ask for more information, add that information to the question itself. A big part of getting good answers is having a complete and clear question. Editing your question to add information is a good thing and is strongly encouraged.

@Ramhound suggested I try the Reset-AppxPackage. I guess it should be done with the MS Store. Where do I find the required parameters?

@VolkerPiasta - It's a DISM command. The UWP package of the Windows Store is well documented. `` should be the package name. Reset-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe is the correct command within PowerShell 7+ Reset-AppxPackage

Due to all the other issues.  I would just rollback your install, which should be possible, provided it's a personal machine not work machine.  If it is then contact your IT Administrator to rollback the system.
